# How can append a string to every number on a text file?

Tags: python, append, newline, readfile, writefile

I have a phone number list,each on a new line and I want to append a string “@ctest.com” to the end of every new line.

```
with open(“demofile.txt”, “r”) as f1: 
    Lines = f1.readlines()
    For x in Lines:
     f= open(“demofile.txt”, “a”)
     f.writelines([“@vtest.com”])
     f.close()

    y = open(“demofile.txt”, “r”)
Print(Y.read())
```

I was expecting each line to print as below

```
7163737373@vtest.com
7156373737@vtest.com
```

For all the files on new lines.

But I got this

```
7163737373
7156373737@vtest.com,vtest.com
```

Comment: Did you post this on a mobile device that automatically capitalizes the first word of a line? `For` and `Print` should not have uppercase letters.

Comment: Remember to turn off "smart quotes" when posting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not appending to each line, you're just appending `@vtestcom` to the end of the file each time through the loop.

You need to reopen the file in write mode, not append mode, and write each `x` from the original `readlines()`.

```
with open("demofile.txt", "r") as f1: 
    lines = f1.readlines()

with open("demofile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(f'{line.strip()}@ctest.com\n')

with open("demofile.txt", "r") as y:
    print(y.read())
```

FYI, this is much easier to do in bash:

```
sed -i 's/$/@vtest.com' demofile.txt
```

Comment: You also have to replace the chars `“` for `"`.

Comment: Cleaner code for the middle part.

```
  f.write("@ctest.com\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: That won't put `@ctest.com` at the end of the last line. And the lines already end with  newlines, that will put `@ctests.com` on its own line between the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, i couldn't use bash because i'm on a windows machine and didn't wanna research alternatives to that but the first answer worked nicely. i'm an infant in this vastness of information. new  on stackoverflow as well and can't see an option to follow you .